# Managing DHCP with Cobbler and multiple NICs

Tags: networking, dhcp, nic, pxe-boot, cobbler

I'm trying to setup Cobbler for PXE booting and I want it to also manage DHCP.  The issue is I only want one of the two available NICs to manage DHCP.  Is there a way to specify which NIC Cobbler will use for DHCP? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are both nics attached to the same subnet?  If not, do you have scopes setup for both subnets?

DHCP servers will only server clients on interfaces that have a valid address within one of the defined scopes.